# probability of being infected by flu

Tags: probability

> A sample of $500$ persons were followed for a month to study the mechanism of people contracting a flu.  Only one person was found to contract flu. But this person contracted twice in a month. For this sample what is the hazard of getting a flu?

What I tried: Probability of getting a person infected with flu $\displaystyle =\frac{1}{500}$

Total sample size $=500$

And person $X$ infected twice in a month

So $$P(X=2)=\binom{100}{1}\left(\frac{1}{500}\right)\left(\frac{499}{500}\right)^{499}$$

Is my answer correct? If not, then please tell me how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: By hazard of getting flue, are you referring to the probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimation of the hazard of getting a flue is $\frac{1}{500}$. The fact that one person got twice the flue is not important to calculate the probability of being infected (think at the fact that 500 guys on 500 get infected twice....the hazard cannot be 200%).

The probability for one guy to get twice a flue in the referred  period can be calculated with a poisson law.

A person can be infected $0,1,2,3,,,908,...$ times

$$\mathbb{P}[X=2]=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{500}}(\frac{1}{500})^2}{2!}$$